# Скрыть элемент после перезагрузки стр

Tags: jquery

В общем, знаю, что этой функцией можно скрыть элемент на странице после клика. Элемент появится на секунду и пропадёт:

```
$("#click").click(function () {
    $("#block").show();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#block").hide();
    }, 1000);
});
```

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы после перезагрузки страницы, элемент появился на странице и пропал через секунду?

Comment: Ой, чет я туплю сори ребят, неактуально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
jQuery(function ($){
    setTimout(function (){
         $('#block').hide();
    }, 1000);
});
```